# MVC Issue: Sign up form, multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

Good Day to all!

Just a little background on my system, VS2013, SQL Server 2012 Management Server.

So I'm still working on my MVC project and current I'm stuck with another issue.

Previously I have a table of employees containing personal information(name, DOB, address, etc), and now I added another table containing work related information(eg. job title, date of hire, etc, etc)

I have created the two models and two views but as my user would like to create a new employee in a single form. I would need to add my work info text fields into my personal info view create page.

I've experimented tuple

```
 "@model Tuple<blah.Models.PersonalInfo, blah.Models.WorkInfo>;"
```

and thus far I am able to generate the fields in the view but I would like to ask, how can I send this information that has been entered by the user back to the table to add a new employee.

(i.e to say, the user click "create" and the form is able to encapsulate the data entered into their separate "models" and query my database to add the new guy)

Comment: Create a view model containing all the properties your want to edit, and post it back, then initialize your 2 data models based on the view model properties.

Comment: how do i initialise my two data models? would you please point me a way? thanks in advance

Comment: In the POST method, `var personal = new PersonalInfo() { name = viewModel.Name, DOB = viewModel.DOB, ...etc }` and ditto for `WorkInfo` then save you `PersonalInfo` and `WorkInfo` models

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a ViewModel instead of passing a tuple.

```
public class EmployeesViewModel
{
    public PersonalInfo PersonalInfo { get ;set; }
    public WorkInfo WorkInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller build up the ViewModel and pass it to the View.

```
public  ActionResult WorkAction()
{
    var personalInfo = new PersonalInfo();
    var workInfo = new WorkInfo();

    var viewModel = new EmployeesViewModel
    {
        viewModel.PersonalInfo = personalInfo,
        viewModel.WorkInfo = workInfo
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And in the View use the following model:

```
@model EmployeesViewModel
```

The ViewModel will then be passed to the controller when you save.

As mentioned in Stephen Muecke's comment you can then initialize your 2 data models based on the view model properties.